# Userid returning null for createportalUser method

Tags: apex

I have a self registration page trying to use createportaluser method. I see the assignment is correct for all user fields. But the userid is returned as null

I did verify the permissions for user creating portal users and they do have access to accounts and contacts

Any thoughts?

Here is the code

```
List<User> exstredy = [select id from user where username =:Email and IsActive = true LIMIT 1];
                system.debug('exstredy' + exstredy );
                if(exstredy .size()>0){
                    showmessage = true;
       message = 'Already a user';
                } else {
                   Contact cn = new Contact();
                   cn.firstName = firstName;
                    cn.LastName =lastName;
                   cn.Email = Email;
                   cn.AccountId = '001o000000ONAbq';
                    insert cn;

 Profile profile = [select Id, name from Profile where Name=: 'Community User'];

                    User u = new User();
                    u.ContactId = cn.Id;
                    u.Username = cn.Email;
                    u.Alias = u.Username.split('@').get(0);
                    u.Email = cn.Email;
                    u.FirstName = cn.firstname ;
                    u.LastName =cn.lastname;
                    u.ProfileId = profile.id;
                    String accountId = c.AccountId;
                 //   u.CommunityNickName = u.Username.split('@').get(0);
                    u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
                    u.LocaleSidKey ='en_CA';
                    u.TimeZoneSidKey ='America/NewYork';
                    u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
                  insert u;
                 system.debug ('username of created user is' +u.Username);
             String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, Password);
                return Site.login(username,password,null);
                }
```

Comment: What do you see in your debug logs?

Comment: In the debug logs, I see all the user assignment values returned with values. The only error I see is null pointer exception where userid is null

Comment: You need to post the relevant parts of your code and explain where the error is occurring.

Comment: I did check the debug logs and see that all the user fields are returning value but the userid is returned as null

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are doing an `insert u` right before the createPortalUser.  There is no need for this because `createPortalUser` will insert the user.